# no matching function for this function in c++

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference

I'm having trouble with this one. I've read some other pages here but I didn't found a solution for this:

This is my code:

```
void Tanque::update(World *world, vector<Fantasma*> *ListaFantasmas){

rot = bearing(rect.x, rect.y, ListaFantasmas->back()->rect.x, ListaFantasmas->back()->rect.y);

bala1-> update(&(ListaFantasmas-> back()));
}
```

the last line gives me an error. (no matchig function for call to bala::update(Fantasma**)

And this is the code for Bala:update:

```
void bala::update(Fantasma *fantasma){

rect.x = rect.x + speed * cos(rot);
rect.y = rect.y + speed * sin(rot);

rot = bearing(rect.x, rect.y, fantasma -> rect.x, fantasma -> rect.y);

}
```

Nothing strange as you can see. I'm passing the parameter by reference in the function, I don't see anything wrong.

What do you think the error could be? How can I solve it?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems in this call

```
bala1-> update(&(ListaFantasmas-> back()));
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

the member function `back` returns a reference to an object of type `Fantasma *` and you are applying operator & to it getting pointer of type `Fantasma **`

Maybe you should call the function just like

```
bala1-> update((ListaFantasmas-> back()));
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

The type of `ListaFantasmas` is `vector<Fantasma*> *`
Hence, the type of the value returned by `ListaFantasmas-> back()` is `Fantasma*`.

The line

```
bala1-> update(&(ListaFantasmas-> back()));
```

is equivalent to:

```
Fantasma* temp = ListaFantasmas-> back();
bala1-> update(&temp);
```

That means, you are trying to pass a `Fantasma**` to a function whose argument type is `Fantasma*`.

**Solution**

You can use:

```
bala1-> update(ListaFantasmas-> back());
```

`
To make it more readable, you can use:

```
Fantasma* temp = ListaFantasmas-> back();
bala1-> update(temp);
```